# Percent Signs in PHP Strings

Tags: php, post, escaping, fwrite

I have this small PHP script that takes a POST variable and writes it out to a file.

```
<?php
   $fileContents = $_POST["Contents"];
   $fileName = $_POST["Name"];
   $filePath = $_POST["Path"];

   $passcode = $_POST["Passcode"];

   if ($passcode != "<passcode>")
      die();

   if (!is_dir("./upload/$filePath"))
      mkdir("./upload/$filePath", 0755, true);

   $file = "./upload/$filePath" . $fileName;

   $fd = fopen($file, "w");
   fwrite($fd, $fileContents);
   fclose($fd);
?>
```

This seems to work fine for most text given, but in the event where text containing a percent sign (%) is given, the following oddity occurs:

```
ﬁvice = getField( %bind, 0 );
```

The original text was:

```
%device = getField( %bind, 0 );
```

I send the POST request with the following server request:

```
POST path/to/Upload.php HTTP/1.1\nHost: host.com\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\nContent-Length: <length>\n\n<file data>\n
```

This also occurs with many other cases, but, as you can see, not with %bind.
I looked for the cause of this and found something on %%, so I tried a %%-escaper and got this:

```
%ﬁvice = getField( %%bind, 0 );
```

Is there any way to fix this % problem? Also, is the % problem a php issue or a request issue?

Edit: I tried using urlencode / urldecode but those both failed to fix the problem. This also occurred with `file_put_contents`, so I'm starting to think it's an upload problem.

Comment: 1.- You are using POST variables without any filter nor test. 2.- What is `getField`?

Comment: This script is a **serious** security hazard.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: I implemented a passcode into it, see the edits. It may not be *the most secure thing*, but it's all I really need for now.

Comment: @Nicolás, `getField` is just the code in the text that is being uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to fix it is to URL-encode the text, which will turn `%` into `%25`. You'll need to investigate where it needs to be encoded though (or why it's not being encoded in the first place).

```
>>> u'ﬁ'.encode('macroman')
'\xde'
```

Comment: Indeed, I was sending the raw % signs as "url-encoded" text to the php, which in turn decoded the % signs into ﬁ characters. I ended up encoding the text before sending it via POST. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps applying a [urldecode](http://php.net/urldecode) to the string? URL encoded characters look like a percentage followed by two numbers, but maybe those can be hexadecimal. `d` and `e` are both hexadecimal numbers ..

%de might be the character ﬁ.

Comment: Indeed, %de is the character ﬁ. And no, I am not urlDecode'ing the string. The php up there is the exact version on my site.